# Why cant I use variable!=+ or variable!=- in C for example

Tags: c

I am doing a simple calculator using switch case but i ran into some problems and decided to do it in another way to check if what the user inputs is invalid but I cant make it work.

this is a piece of code from the program:

```
if (choice!="+"&&choice!="-"&&choice!="*"&&choice!="/");
    {
    printf("The type of operation is invalid\n");
    invalid=1;
    printf("Chose the type of operation, + for sum, - for subtraction, * for multiplication and / for division\n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    }
```

I cant verify if what the user inputs is different than +, -,, * or /.

I would love some help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `'` instead of `"` for 1 char

Comment: use single quotes around character constants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: Actually, since the OP didn't give us the declaration of `choice`, it could be either.  If choice is a `char` you want to test against a `char`, i.e. `'+'`.  If choice is a `char *` you need to test with `strcmp`.

Comment: @user2064000: Your suggestions assume `choice` is a string, what it most likely isn't (see the call to `scanf`).

Comment: You also have a semicolon (`;`) after your if statement before the `{`, so the if statement will be ignored. I recommend using the syntax `if(something){` instead (with the `{` on the same line as the if statement) because it makes it less likely to make such mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, I see the following statement:

`scanf("%c", &choice);`

So I am judging that the type of the variable 'choice' is char.

For character comparison, you need to use a single quote, not double quotes. So replace the

`if (choice!="+"&&choice!="-"&&choice!="*"&&choice!="/");`

with

`if (choice!='+'&&choice!='-'&&choice!='*'&&choice!='/')`

Also, remove the semicolon from the end of the `if` statement. It doesn't make sense.